# Reading a column with wide range of numbers and characters in sas

Tags: sas

My dataset has a column with a wide range of values in it, such as the one below:

Value

3223145.306

1.044303129

345.556033

17693.00837

**8.03E-06**

**NaN**

**1.97E-04**

**2.29E-04**

**8.01E-04**

**7.46E-04**

18345.82237

47.78282804

**4.14E-06**

When I read this column in SAS, observations are read as character. Once I convert this to numeric the observations with E-04, E-05, E-06, etc. are being converted to 1.9736273 instead of 0.00019736273.

How do I account for E-04, E-05, E-05 etc.?

code for character to numeric:

Value=input(Value, best12.);

Comment: Why would SAS read it as character?  Did you ask SAS to GUESS how to read it? Perhaps by using PROC IMPORT?

Comment: Hello Tom, thank you for responding. Yes, I am using PROC Import to read in the file. proc import datafile= "&loc.\&exid..xlsx"
 out=dt                       
 dbms=xlsx replace; 
  range="'Exp_Data_Tbl'$A2:AB10000";
  getnames=yes;
run;

Comment: With XLSX you have no control over how SAS converts the cells into values.  If even only one of the cells in a column has that NaN string then SAS will have to make the variable be character to support that.  If instead you were reading from a text file, like a CSV file, then you could decide how to read the variable by writing your own data step to read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make a NEW variable if you want it to have a different type.

The INPUT function does not care if the width used on the informat is larger than the length of the string being read.  So just use the maximum width that the informat supports.  Also BEST is the name of a FORMAT, not an INFORMAT.  If you use as the name of an informat then SAS will just default to using the normal numeric informat. So just go ahead and say that from the start instead of confusing format names for informat names.

The normal numeric informat can read those strings as numbers. So this code will work to create a new numeric variable named NUMBER from the existing character variable named VALUE.

```
number = input(VALUE,32.);
```

The only string in your list that will cause any issues is the string 'NaN'.  SAS will not know how to translate that so you will just get a missing value as the result.  Which is basically what systems that use that "not a number" symbol mean by it anyway.  To prevent the notes in the log you can either test for it explicitly.

```
if upcase(value) not in ('NA','N/A','NAN') then number=input(value,32.);
```

Or just suppress the error messages by add the ?? modifier.

```
number=input(value,??32.);
```

But then you will not get any message if there is other gibberish in the value variable.

Comment: Thank you @Tom, Both, number = input(VALUE,32.); and if upcase(value) not in ('NA','N/A','NAN') then number=input(value,32.); work. Also, thank you for the format, informat knowledge above. I will keep that in mind.